# Get the above tr in a table with a specific class

Tags: jquery, html

What i'm trying to do is: i'm having a table that looks like this

```
<table>
    <tr class="warning">
        <input type="hidden" name="ID[]" value="1" />
        <td>warning</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="editField">edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="editField">edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="editField">edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="warning">
        <input type="hidden" name="ID[]" value="2" />
        <td>warning</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="editField">edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And for each warning `tr` there is an hidden input with specific ID.
I've tried:

```
$.each($('a.editField'), function(i,obj){
   console.log($(obj).parent().parent().prevAll('tr.warning').find('[name="ID[]"]').val());
});
```

But it's logging me the first `warning` `tr` in the table, so the log will be four times ID 1,
and what it should be is three times ID 1 and one time ID 2.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dLp7b/

Comment: What you are trying to do ?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I want to know for each tr who is the tr above him but only if it has warning class

Comment: Sorry! I didn't get it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing `:first`. That would give you the first closest sibling.

```
$.each($('a.editField'), function(i,obj){
    console.log($(obj).parent().parent().prevAll('tr.warning:first').find('[name="ID[]"]').val());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dLp7b/1/)